# Should I activate my new credit card if my name is misspelled on it?

Tags: credit-card

I recently got a credit card and the name on my credit card is misspelled. I've already called the company and they said I'll get a new one in 2 weeks. Should I activate my card with misspelled name on it? The numbers are the same, so it shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: There are digits on the backs of the card that may be different as issuing a new card may mean a new set of digits on the back of the card.  As some places will ask for these digits, I'd wait for the correct card to arrive before activating one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wait for the card with your name spelled correctly and activate that one. This will make your life easier in several ways:

1. It's less of a hassle if someone needs to check your ID against your card.
2. You won't have to worry about an incorrect name showing up on your credit history, or about items *not* showing up on your credit history because the names don't match.
3. If the names don't match, you may receive fraud alerts if you attempt to use your card online and enter your correct name. The credit card company will notice that someone with a "different name" is trying to use your card.

Comment: #2 - from my experience, it will probably show up. I had an exactly the same situation once, and that misspelled name appears as alias ever since.

Comment: I was at first thinking it would be OK to use it online, but then I remembered that the webform asks for the name on the card. So it would get confusing because you would have no idea which name you should put on the form. Just because it takes two weeks to send you a card doesn't mean that they didn't fix the database right after you called.